# Acer Aspire heats up in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: battery, acer, overheating, hybrid-graphics

I have an Acer Aspire 4820TG. It heats up in Ubuntu while remains cool in Windows 7. Consequently, the battery backup in Ubuntu is very low.

Why is it so?  I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 graphic card on my machine. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: 10.10 is not supported anymore with updates or security patches, so problems that may be fixed in other versions will remain broken/vulnerable in this version.  I would suggest you upgrade to another version.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop model has hybrid graphics system. In linux both the graphics card is on all the time and causing overheat and reduced battery life.

If your system has graphical multiplexer, (change grphics card in BIOS) You can use `vgaswitcheroo` mechanism of kernel to turnoff it. But this feature is available in newer kernel. **I recommend you to upgrade ubuntu to 12.04.**

Read more:

https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.in/2012/01/improved-support-for-amd-hybrid.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450